# The source attachment does not contain the source for the file logger.class

Tags: java, sql, logging

I am debugging a large application that someone else wrote . When I run the application and put in my credentials, the program starts executing SQL queries. Although these are legit SQL queries that works in the database itself, however I get SQL exceptions that it can not retrieve the information. When I debug my code in eclipse by stepping though the code, I get source attachment does not contain the source for the file logger.class, But I don't get this error when I just run the application without stepping through that segment of the code. I just get the SQL exception after credentials are put in. The program is able to login to the database as far as I know. I know it is probably hard to to tell, but is there a relationship between the logger problem and the SQL statment.

Thank you greatly for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found out that stepping through the code in Eclipse might give that error for the source attachment non-existent. But it was irreverent in my case. It was actually the SQL statements that weren't legit. I fixed them and now the code is working.